# How to serialize a simple Dict using django-marshmallow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, marshmallow

I tried all the ways and when I validate the serializer by calling is_valid(), I always get an error.

```
class KVSFileMapSerializer(Schema):
    kv_map = fields.Dict()

kvs_result = {
    'trial': 'Config',
    'trial_1': 'Congig',
}

kvs_serializer = KVSFileMapSerializer(data=kvs_result)
kvs_serializer.is_valid()
```

The last line always returns 'False', I tried raising an exception and this is what I get,

> {'trial': [ErrorDetail(string='Unknown field.', code='invalid')],
> 'trial_1': [ErrorDetail(string='Unknown field.', code='invalid')]}

This is the package that I use - [django-marshmallow](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/django-rest-marshmallow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a serializer with some fields you need to pass the same field to the serializer in order for the serializer to serialize the data.

```
kvs_result = {
    "trial": "Config",
    "trial_1": "Congig",
}
```

this data does not contain the serializer field key i.e `kv_map` so that why `kvs_serializer.is_valid()` will always return `False`.

**Correct Data:**

```
data = {"kv_map": {"trial": "Config", "trial_1": "Congig",}}
```

as you have defined the kv_map field as `kv_map = fields.Dict()` you need to pass a dictionary with its key as `kv_map` and its value a dictionary.